# sending multiple JSON Objects lists in node js

Tags: json, node.js, express

I am new to node.js can anyone tell me how to send multiple database rows using res.send() method ?in above code i fetch multiple rows from database but when i put those data into res.send() it doesn't working on for loop and gives me error like " throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
 ^

**Can't set headers after they are sent."**

app.post('/getUserList.htm',function(req,res){

```
console.log("Controller called..");

var Obj=req.body.json;
var data=JSON.parse(Obj);
console.log("Json is: " + data[0].username);
var query="SELECT * FROM app_user";
connect.connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
    if(err){
        console.log("Error is: "+err);
    }else{
        var jsonObject={};
        var key = 'detail';
        jsonObject[key] = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { 
            console.log("UserName is :" + rows[i].SSO_ID);
            var details={
                "username":rows[i].SSO_ID,
                "PhoneNO" :rows[i].Wallet_Number
        };
            jsonObject[key].push(details);
            //JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
            console.log("JSON IS: " + jsonObject[key].userName);
            res.send({
            "data" :{   
        }
        }); 
        }

    }
});
```

});

Comment: Please makes your code readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass you jsonObject variable in response that all. And it good have more parameter in your response to identify your response type.

```
connect.connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
 if(err){
        console.log("Error is: "+err);
        res.send({
            success: false,
            code: 401,
            error : error
        });
    }else{
        var jsonObject={};
        var key = 'detail';
        jsonObject[key] = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { 
            console.log("UserName is :" + rows[i].SSO_ID);
            var details={
                "username":rows[i].SSO_ID,
                "PhoneNO" :rows[i].Wallet_Number
            };
            jsonObject[key].push(details);
            console.log("loop executes "+ i +"th time.."+rows[i].SSO_ID);
            //JSON.stringify(jsonObject);       
        }
        res.send({
            success: true,
            code: 200,
            data :jsonObject
        });
    }
}
```